# How to get good results from the 2023 Developer Survey which requires disabling security and privacy software

Tags: discussion, survey

> Calling all who code. [Take the 2023 Developer Survey](https://stackoverflow.az1.qualtrics.com/jfe/form/SV_czLVsbnGnF4Q04e?utm_source=WTAF&utm_medium=display&utm_campaign=dev-survey-2023&utm_content=take-the-survey)

And then when you get there:

> **If you use security or ad-blocking plugins, you may see error messages**
>
> Our third-party software provider, Qualtrics, does not work well with
> certain ad blockers and security software. To avoid error messages
> that prevent you from taking the survey, please try specifically
> unblocking Qualtrics in your plugin or pausing the plugin while you
> take the survey.

Why did Stack Overflow choose this tool when wanting to do a developer survey about AI? Surely you know that a large sub-set of developers are pro-privacy and pro-security.

I'd also suggest - in my limited experience - that those developers who *are* into security and privacy and thus are anti-surveillance capitalism, overlap a lot with those who see recent AI advances as yet another means to concentrate power in the hands of a tiny group of corporations; to further entrench and forever reproduce prejudices; to erode trust in online content; or have other such reservations.

So how can SE/SO hope to get any realistic results with a survey designed with such a massive bias in place?

Comment: "Surely you know that a large sub-set of developers are pro-privacy and pro-security." - they know, but don't really care

Comment: (a) How do you know the goal is to "GET ... REALISTIC" results? We may only guess. There is the same probability the goal is not to get ... realistic results, but (any) RESULTS, the more participants the better, whereas the actual results do not matter at all ( as having zero chance of being independently reviewed, audited & cross-validated against (already) published "interpretations" ( of publicly never seen "DATA" ). After yesterdays U.S. hearings, where Rep. Blumenthal re-played "deep-fake-synth'd" voice of bot having imitated himself, our awareness must grow & fast ... G/L & Gott mit uns!

Comment: (b) How do you know the very goal is not to *"**create**" thus motivated **bias***, once having "removed" the very knowledgeable part of the "spectre-of-opinions", the (never seen "DATA") *"**fellow-interpreteurs**"* will have free hands & spend less efforts to *"**judge**"* & publish any wishful propaganda about what the "masses-of-IT-pros" actually "do" + "want" + "tolerate" + "whatever"? People who had prior personal experience with theirs own lives under totalitarian regimes can **detect** this & can **decode** such flaws way better, than people without such horrible past, who run into it.

Comment: Yes, noticeable from the outset: `https://stackoverflow.az1.qualtrics.com` ... *"Javascript* ***[sic]*** *is required to load this page"*. Though [allowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoScript) JavaScript code from `...qualtrics.com` was the only required change.

Answer (score 10):

> Surely you know that a large sub-set of developers are pro-privacy and pro-security.

Those people are also less inclined to fill out surveys, any way.

Besides, it's not as if adblockers are guaranteed to break the survey. I've taken quite a few anti-ad measures, and the survey worked just fine, for me.
**It's just a disclaimer stating it *might* break.**

> So how can SE/SO hope to get any realistic results with a survey designed with such a massive bias in place?

What alternatives do you suggest?
As far as I can see, the only option would be to not do a survey at all...

Imho, that "bias" you're talking about seems a little exaggerated.

Comment: "*I've taken quite a few anti-ad measures, and the survey worked just fine, for me.*" Yep indeed, same for me, after taking 5.99 Surveys over the years, (the "0.99" is for 2023), in different Browsers (always 'Pale Moon' or 'Firefox'), and I've always had some Ad-Blocker (usually 'uBlock [something]') and I never had to disable them... (FF111 + 'uBlock Origin' v1.42.0 this year.) // Fun Fact, the Survey also still (2023) works in FF v55.0.3 + 'uBlock Origin' v1.17.4, but doesn't work anymore in PM v26.3.3 + 'uBlock Origin' v1.13.8.)

Comment: There are many alternatives. There isn't just one survey platform! Google open source survey platform, perhaps?

Comment: Other survey platforms are equally liable to break with adblockers or other privacy extensions...